# Is it possible to make Heroku install the mongodb NPM package with the C++ BSON parser?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, heroku, npm, bson

Locally, I can run `npm install --mongodb:native` to get npm to compile and install the C++ BSON parser, but I can't replicate the same action on Heroku.

I tried adding a pre-install command `npm install mongodb --mongodb:native` to `package.json` but `npm` isn't actually available on the path in the Heroku environment.

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/christkv/node-mongodb-native/blob/master/install.js) for the mongodb package, it looks like it's looking for an environment variable (created by npm based on the command line argument I guess). Maybe there's a way of injecting that into the Heroku build environment?

BSON (de)serialisation is becoming a big CPU + memory hog for my app, and the C++ parser helps alleviate this.

Comment: You can create a custom buildpack. [Check here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpack-api) for more info.